# What's the most environmentally friendly micro USB charging cable...if any?

Tags: ecological-footprint, green-it, product-design

USB cables seem to be a small but relentless part of throw-away culture. Inevitably, cables stop working well and/or get lost, and a new one is needed.

**Are there any USB cables produced with minimal environmental footprint in mind?**

When I try to search the web for this sort of thing, all I get is gimmicky plastic garbage designed to harness renewable energy (i.e. "window mounted portable solar panel to charge your phone from the sun during your commute!" - the irony is killing me, among other things)

Comment: The shorter the better...

Comment: Perhaps it makes sense to generalize this to "phone charging cables"? That would include Apple's lightning cables, and USB-C which is starting to become more common.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just buy a used USB cable.  You can go to a computer recycler and they will have thousands.

Comment: The question specifically asks about _production_ of USB cables -- though you make a valid point, this works better as a comment on the question.

Comment: @LShaver Then OP is asking the wrong question.   There is an excess of cables as they outlast the device.

Comment: I think this answers the title question "What's the most environmentally friendly micro USB charging cable…if any?" with "a used one".

Answer (score 1):

You can always learn to solder, and make your own cables. By re-using electronic scrap you'll prevent the need for new cables. Then it can be as long as you need.

Comment: Solder?  Have you ever soldered a USB?

Comment: https://www.androidcentral.com/weekend-project-diy-usb-go-old-cables

Comment: Yes I actually have.

Comment: I used to have computer repair shop and I never soldered a cable.  I had 100s of cables from machines that went bad.

Comment: so, you're saying free cables?

Comment: Yes, in the business cables are free.  Devices fail faster than cables.